# How to declare multiple template in same state having same controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want one state and need to define two different views for that state having same controller.
A dummy code for reference to understand what I want to do is.

```
//view 1
<div>
<p>This is View One</p>
</div>
//View 2
<div>
<p>This is View One</p>
</div>
//This is my state
.state('myState',{
templateUrl:view1,view2//This is what I need
controller:'sameController'//for both views controller should be same
});
```

Comment: see this https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function for the templateUrl.  Pseudo code below:

```
   templateUrl: function ($stateParams){
       if (thisCondition === foo) {
           return 'view1.html';
       } else if (thisCondition === bar) {
           return 'view2.html';
       }
   }
```